# Using a dynamic key to access JSON works, but also throws the error "Cannot read property of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, key

I've been searching all over for an answer to this but haven't found anyone else mentioning an issue like this. I've tried several variations and potential solutions to no avail.

I have the following JSON file:

```js
{
    "subpatterns": {
        "sub1": {
            "selected": "V",
            // other properties not important for this example
        },
        "sub2": {
            "selected": "C",
            // other properties not important for this example
        },
        "sub3": {
            "selected": "N",
            // other properties not important for this example
        }
    },
    // other properties not important for this example
}
```

I'm then accessing that data and calling a function on each of the keys under "subpatterns" with the following code:

```js
subPs.startup = function () {
    function addStartData() {
        for (var i = 1; i <= Object.keys(subPs.data.subpatterns).length + 1; i++) {
            subPs.addRow(); // I want to add one more row than the amount of data I have (i.e. one blank row at the end), which is why the for loop is .length + 1
            var selected = subPs.data.subpatterns["sub" + i].selected; // This is where it throws the error
            console.log(selected); // But this works
            if (selected !== undefined) {
                subPs.selectSub(i, selected); // And this works, too
            }
        }
        subPs.checkDupes();
    }
    var json = $.getJSON("../data/gen.json", function (json) {
            subPs.data = json;
            addStartData();
    });
};
```

The code executes correctly. The functions `subPs.addRow()` and `subPs.selectSub()` both add the correct data to the DOM, including the information from the JSON/the variable `selected`. Additionally, calling `console.log(selected)` logs the correct results. And yet the console logs an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of undefined
    at addStartData (gen.js:28)
    at Object.success (gen.js:41)
    at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

How can `subPs.data.subpatterns["sub" + i]` be undefined, yet also work correctly? And how can I solve the error?

I tried using `["sub1"]` instead of using a dynamic key, and that did *not* throw the error.

Comment: Why are you reconstructing the keys with `"sub" + i` in the first place, given that `Object.keys(subPs.data.subpatterns)` returns an array with the actual key names so you could just iterate over that?

Comment: @nnnnnn The reason I'm using `"sub" + i` is to make 100% sure that the number is identical when called in `subPs.selectSub(i, selected);`, and because I want to be sure they're accessed in order. Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like an idiot. Apparently I only needed to sleep on it.

I was checking if `subPs.data.subpatterns["sub" + i].selected` exists *after* the variable assignment, but I really needed to be checking if `subPs.data.subpatterns["sub" + i]` exists *before* the variable assignment.

```js
subPs.startup = function () {
    function addStartData() {
        for (var i = 1; i <= Object.keys(subPs.data.subpatterns).length + 1; i++) {
            subPs.addRow(); // I want to add one more row than the amount of data I have (i.e. one blank row at the end), which is why the for loop is .length + 1
            if (subPs.data.subpatterns["sub" + i] !== undefined) { // Putting the variable assignment in this if statement fixed the issue
                var selected = subPs.data.subpatterns["sub" + i].selected;
                subPs.selectSub(i, selected);
            }
        }
        subPs.checkDupes();
    }
    var json = $.getJSON("../data/gen.json", function (json) {
            subPs.data = json;
            addStartData();
    });
};
```

Primarily, I was checking the wrong property for existence.

Answer (score 0):

I Feel problem is in for loop, It should be like

```
for (var i = 1; i <= Object.keys(subPs.data.subpatterns).**length;** i++)
```

instead of

```
for (var i = 1; i <= Object.keys(subPs.data.subpatterns).**length + 1**; i++)
```

because this will try to get one more object from array and it will be always `undefined`.

Comment: I've added a clarifying comment to my original question. I want to create 1 blank row, so one additional row beyond the data I have.

Comment: Empty row should be added after loop complete. That will be a good approach and there will not be chance for undefined object

Comment: You are Welcome